How can I connect 4 wires to this light switch?
I'm trying to change the Bathroom light switch. (It is a single switch) Both the light and the extractor are connected to this switch.

I have now purchased a new switch that looks like this:

How can connect the 4 cables into this? I believe the correct way is to put both live wires (brown) into COM.  And both neutral (blue) wires into L1.
Can someone confirm this please?
Many Thanks

Can you add what country are you in?  This is not typical North American appliance.   I'm assuming UK.
And  pictures of the front of the units.   I have to assume that the first picture shows the back of two ganged separate switches.  But the color of the connections to the lower switch is suspect as you have a blue wire in a brown terminal.     In any case, COM would be neutral, and the Loads, should go in the L terminals.   Someone with more UK experience can answer better.

Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that. I'm, in UK.

It's just the bathroom light switch at the door.

What's wrong with the old switch?

Plastic part inside is damaged, the switch pops back, can't turn it on anymore.

The old switch is a two-pole one.   I'm guessing you have two switch legs from two locations, eg one from a light on the ceiling, and another from an extractor on the wall.  Perhaps long-ago there were two switches, and you or a previous owner wanted one-switch control so installed a two-pole switch.
The new switch is not two-pole, it is two-way, so things can be controlled from multiple places e.g. top and bottom of stairs.  You can't use that here.
If I'm right about the wiring, IE it's two switch legs from two different locations and you want one-switch control, the only way to do it is with another two-pole switch.   In the line of switches you have purchased,that would be the model 830 or 930.

You bought the wrong kind of switch.
The original switch was a dual-pole (or 2-pole) switch. It can switch 2 wires at the same time, with just one rocker on the front side. According to the markings, it was meant to switch both live and neutral, but as it was used in your case it switches two live wires.
The new switch you bought is a 2-way (or 3-way, depending on your location) switch. It can connect the COM terminal either with the L1 or the L2 terminal. This type of switch is commonly used to control a single light from 2 places.
As a side note, you don't have neutral in the box. The blue wires are NOT neutral, but switched hot.

The previous bathroom switch was a single pole. It had only one switch, and no other room could control it.
I ended up connecting both brown cables to COM and both blue cables with brown collars to L1.  Do you think this is wrong? Based on this website, it should be ok: https://socketstore.co.uk/page/help/sockets-switches/how-to-wire-a-light-switch

Sorry, the upper photo is the broken light switch. The bottom photo is the new switch that I bought.

@Houman, with the new switch you can get either the fan or the light on, but never both together on or both off. That is probably not the behavior you wanted to have. Note that a dual-pole switch switches two wires at the same time, with one action at one place. The old switch provides a make/break contact between the blue terminals and a separate make/break contact between the brown terminals. Both contacts are controlled by a single rocker on the front and are either both connected or both disconnected.

I'm not sanguine about the other two answers.  But this appears to be the switch in question (PCDBS12W): https://www.bgelectrical.uk/uk/wiring-devices/evolve/finishes/brushed-steel/20a-16ax-light-switches
Note that Europe calls these 2-location switches "2-way" where we Yanks call them "3-way."
See the "Two Way Switching" instructions here: https://res.cloudinary.com/lucecoplc/raw/upload/v1691470378/Websites-prod/300807/BG_IM_NXPSWIL_K.pdf
You can see the brown-sleeved wires in the OP's pic, as noted in the instructions.
Note, IDK what the other switch location looks like, so I'm only 99% certain the above is correct.  Maybe OP can add a pic of the back of that one.
